# How to have page change upon clicking <a> tag in JEditorPane?

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe, jeditorpane

I have an "a" element on an html page with an href for a different website. Currently, when I click on the a element on the page displayed in the JEditorPane, the site the JEditorpane doesn't change the site. It won't redirect to the href's location. How would I fix this while keeping the redirected page displayed in the JEditorPane? Thank you!

**The site's code in question is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://reddit.com"><img src="cat.jpeg" width="300" height="300" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**The JFrame and JEditorPane's code is:**

```
public class Gui 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JEditorPane htmlContent = new JEditorPane();

    public void loadScreen() throws MalformedURLException, IOException 
    {
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setOpacity(1.0F);
        htmlContent.setEditable(false);
        htmlContent.setPage(new URL("RANDOM SITE"));
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(htmlContent));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the links displayed in a `JEditorPane` to load a new page in the pane on mouse click, you need to add a listener, something like this:

```
htmlContent.addHyperlinkListener(e->{
    if ( e.getEventType () == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED ) {
        URL url = e.getURL ();
        // fetch the new page from the URL and load it into the JEditorPane
    }
});
```